# Operator in $C[0,1]$ doesn't contradict the open mapping theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $V$ be the space of real continuous functions in $C[0,1]$, with the norm $\max_{t\in [0,1]} \{ |f(t)| \}$. Then, define $T:V \to W$ as,
$$T(f)(x)=\int_0^x f(s)ds,$$
for all $x\in[0,1]$.
Then,

1. Find $W$.
2. Show that $T$ is lineal, continuous and a bijection
3. Show that $T^{-1}$ is not continuous.

---

Now, since $T(f)(x)$ is differentiable then it is continuous then, I know at least $W\subseteq V$.
For the second part, linearity is derived from integrals, continuity for the same reason I mentioned before. Then I try to show it is an injective and surjective function, so if for $x_0$, $\int_0^x f(s)ds = \int_0^x g(s)ds$, then $$\int_0^x [f(s)-g(s)]ds=0$$
However I haven't found an argument to conclude $f(s)=g(s)$.
For the surjectivity, I will have to prove every function can be written as an integral, however, I don't know if that's true.

Lastly, $T^{-1}$ will not be continuous by finding a sequence that converges a number but which evaluated in the derivative of a function will not, but, this not contradicts the Open Mapping Theorem?

Comment: It is not declared what norm $W$ is equipped with. For example if $W=C_0'[0,1]$ with norm $\|f'\|_\infty,$  then $T$ is a bijective isometry .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. "Finding $W$" is a weird request, because there is no canonical reason nor way to choose the codomain of a function. The way the questions are phrased, though, it seems that they want you to look for the range of $T$. This is the space of continuously differentiable functions that vanish at zero.
2. The continuity (boundedness is the more appropriate word in the context) of $T$ is trivially seen by
   $$
   |Tf(x)|\leq\int_0^x|f(t)|\,dt\leq\|f\|_\infty \,\int_0^11\,dt=\|f\|_\infty. 
   $$
   So $\|Tf\|\leq\|f\|_\infty$, which tells you that $T$ is bounded and $\|T\|\leq1$.

The surjectivity of $T$ was guaranteed by the definition of $W$. The injectivity follows from the fact that if $\int_0^xf=0$ for all $x$, then $f=0$. This follows by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (since $f$ is continuous), as $f(x)=d/dx\,\int_0^x f=0$ for all $x$.

3. The inverse is not continuous. Note that $T^{-1}$ is the derivation operator. Let $g_n(t)=t^n$. Then $\|g\|_\infty=1$ for all $n$. But since $(T^{-1}g_n)(t)=nt^{n-1}$, we have that $\|T^{-1}g_n\|=n$. So $T^{-1}$ is unbounded.

There is no contradiction with the Open Mapping Theorem because $W$ is not Banach.

Comment: The range of $T$ consists of functions which vanish  $0.$ and are continuously differentiable.

Comment: Of course. Thanks for noticing!